# mysql find duplicates across multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing date fields. Is there any way I could find entries in table where there are common dates between `date1` and `date2`.
Here's how my table looks like

```
|   date1  |   date2  |
_______________________
| 20140201 | 20140203 |
| 20140205 | 20140207 |
| 20140202 | 20140201 |
| 20140206 | 20140202 |
```

I would like to find dates

```
20140201 
20140202
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT dates FROM (
    SELECT date1 as dates
    FROM your_table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT date2
    FROM your_table
) sq
GROUP BY dates
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Or better

```
SELECT DISTINCT
yt1.date1
FROM your_table yt1
INNER JOIN your_table yt2 ON yt1.date1 = yt2.date2;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to compare the value of your two columns with two SQL request like it:

```
SELECT date1 FROM yourtable WHERE date1 IN ( SELECT date2 FROM yourtable)
```